# ComboBox in windows forms Datagridview control

Tags: windows, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview on a windows form. It has clolumn [`EmployeeNumber, EmployeeName and EmployeeDepartment`].

I want to be able to edit values directly in the grid but i want EmployeeDepartment to be a combobox column, such that on cell edit, a combobox shows up with available options for the employee department. Has any one been able to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 5):

The `DataGridView` actually has a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.  If you go to the column designer, and add a new column you'll notice you can select one of a few types.  It behaves exactly as you have described - on edit, it appears.  The `DataGridView` uses things called editing controls, and has various events for swapping the control into the cell on edit.

Either way, if all you want is a drop-down, that's available out of the box.

To populate the combo box with items, in the column editor you will notice that it has an `Items` property for manually setting items, or you can use the data binding properties: `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember`.  Data-binding has issues when an expected value is not in the items collection, you will get a lot of cell errors; but they can be avoided.

Some helpful links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e8e2d9eb-fe39-42ab-9a18-2194dac54675/

Comment: If i set the columnType to Combobox column, only the current value for the department is displayed in combobox, How can i show all the possible option. I have a list of departments in a table.